# Fetch zipcode from latlng

Tags: android, zipcode

Which webservice should i use to get the zipcode from latitude and longitude?
I am using Geonames API but it doesnot meet the requirement. I want to use anyother webservices which provides the zipcode/postalcode.

```
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(_mylat, _mylong, 1);
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
        String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                        String zipcode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
```

Even I tried this code but i didnt get the result. I got the Exception as IndexOutOfBoundException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Geocoder geocoder;
            List<Address> addresses;
            geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(_mylat, _mylong, 1);
            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String city = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            String country = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                            String zipcode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
```

Comment: i hve done the same as u said. But its showing exceotion like this  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.zipcode/com.example.zipcode.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Answer (score 0):

From the tag, I assume you're developing an Android app. If that's the case, I would suggest  using [`Geocoder.getFromLocation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation%28double,%20double,%20int%29), instead of a webservice.

Given latitude and location, it will produce a list of possible `Address` objects. You can then use [`getPostalCode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html#getPostalCode%28%29) to get their zipcode.

See [Displaying a Location Address](http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) for a tutorial.